# reaction between copper metal and aqueous sodium bicarbonate

Tags: reaction-mechanism

I wanted to know what reaction would occur between copper metal and sodium bicarbonate?

I believe that once in sodium bicarbonate solution, the copper metal will go into solution as copper ions and replace the sodium ions. Is this wrong?

Also, if it is indeed true, what would the reaction between copper ions and bicarbonate ions be?

Comment: There would be no reaction.

Comment: why? is it because copper cannot replace sodium

Comment: You may put it this way, if you like. In my opinion, non-existence of something does not require a reason; existence does.

Comment: Aqueous sodium bicarbonate indeed reacts with $\ce{Cu^2+}$ but not copper metal. see this:- http://chemiday.com/en/reaction/3-1-0-5035

Comment: okay, but will there at least be copper ions in solution from the copper metal?

Answer (score 1):

First, reduction potentials.

Theory page
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_potential?wprov=sfla1

Table of standard electrode potentials
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_electrode_potential_%28data_page%29?wprov=sfla1

Standard electrode potentials of sodium is -2.70V while copper (I) is 5.20V, single electron reduction of copper (II) has 1.59V, full reduction potential is 3.37V

Higher the reduction potential, more the tendency for the species itself to reduce. Reduction potential of Copper is much higher than Sodium.

So conclusion is no.

Lets say if copper can replace sodium. By how much? Under room conditions, RT/F*lne is approximately 0.06V, so the amount of copper ions that will replace sodium will be orders of magnitude 71.5 to 115 times dilute. In other words, non existant.

Comment: The standards electrode  potential go copper 2 is 0.337V and 0.159 for copper 2 copper ion.

Answer (score 1):

It can react, but at oxygen presence to oxidize copper, slowly forming famous greenish basic copper carbonate. In a mineral form, it is known as malachite.

One of possible reactions:

$$\ce{2 Cu + O2 +  HCO3- + H2O -> CuCO3 . Cu(OH)2 + OH-}$$